# AngularS - Change directive template or rather use a separate one?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am implementing a view that shows blocks of data of two different types. They vary just slightly, in fact, there is just one field that needs to be labeled differently, depending on the current used type of data.

I can see two possible solutions:

- Create two separate directives
- Create just one directive and change its template

Which one should I go for, considering performance? Also, if I should change the template, what would be the best practice to do so?

Answer (score 1):

If the two types only vary slightly, I would suggest using the same directive with just this little switch. But it depends on how you define slightly, I guess.